# Change the ticks of x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a graph which has x-axis values = [151383,151433,175367,178368,183937]
corresponding y-axis values = [98,96,95,100,90]

X-axis values are not at regular intervals. But I want x-axis should be at regular at interval.
if i just write

```
matplotlib.pyplot(y)
```

then the interval is regular and x-axis comes as [1,2,3,4,5]
how can i change that to actual x-axis values?

Comment: can you not just plot (x,y)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> xval=[151383,151433,175367,178368,183937]
>>> y=[98, 96, 95, 100, 90]
>>> x=range(len(xval))
>>> plt.xticks(x,xval)
>>> plt.plot(x,y)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: you've missed the `plot`

Comment: No. 151383 and 151433 are near but rest are far...i want that between each value there should be identical spacing

Comment: because if x-axis changes like =[151388,151390,151400,151899,181004] then first 4 points will be too near and to see any visible difference. actually x-axis are run-number so it should be at equal spaces. I get those run-number(id) generated from some other server

Comment: @AlankritaGupta, I've changed my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just plot with (x, y) and x-axis is the actual values with regular intervals, if that's what you're asking?

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, y) # with the plot by the way
```

Comment: No. 151383 and 151433 are near but rest are far...i want that between each value there should be identical spacing. because if x-axis changes like =[151388,151390,151400,151899,181004] then first 4 points will be too near and to see any visible difference. actually x-axis are run-number so it should be at equal spaces. I get those run-number(id) generated from some other server

Comment: @AlankritaGupta, so you want visible gap between points with regular intervals?

Comment: yes.. beacuse in future my x-value can also become like [151388, 151389,151400,20003948,18479494]

Comment: so i will not use regular intervals then it will be like a straight line in first two points and then large interval in others

Comment: @AlankritaGupta, but since difference between x1, x2 is marginal, if you want to see the visible difference with **regular** x-axis labels, you have to scale the figure

Comment: how can i do that?? do u mean put tick marks at interval of 2 or small number?? but if i do that and if sometime the difference between max and min value comes around 1000(which will) then graph will again not look good....as i said it will be like less spacing(or straight line) where difference is less

Comment: @AlankritaGupta, there is no other way round, but since you've said the x may have more closer points at later stage, unless the max(x)-min(x) is too large, scaling is the obvious solution to show x's difference

Comment: if you just want visible x whereas regular x-interval is not required, then we can set the xticks to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

What about doing something like this? (This is Paul Ivanov's example)

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# If you're not familiar with np.r_, don't worry too much about this. It's just 
# a series with points from 0 to 1 spaced at 0.1, and 9 to 10 with the same spacing.
x = np.r_[0:1:0.1, 9:10:0.1]
y = np.sin(x)

fig,(ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

# plot the same data on both axes
ax.plot(x, y, 'bo')
ax2.plot(x, y, 'bo')

# zoom-in / limit the view to different portions of the data
ax.set_xlim(0,1) # most of the data
ax2.set_xlim(9,10) # outliers only

# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off') # don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()

# Make the spacing between the two axes a bit smaller
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.15)

plt.show()
```

Comment: No. 151383 and 151433 are near but rest are far...i want that between each value there should be identical spacing.

Comment: I updated my original post to reflect what i believe you want to do.

Comment: this results in 2 subplots in a graph..one from (0,1) and second from (9,10)...is it not psbl in single plot?